# Single method for different parameterized mysql command

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have these two methods. One method returns all records, while the other one returns only a specific record.

```
function GetLeaveRequestDetailsAll($leaveCurrentStatus){

    global $connPDO;

    $sql = "select *, emp.Employee_Name, emp.Designation, emp.Emp_Dept_Category, lt.Leave_Name
            from tbl_emp_leave_details eld
            Inner join tbl_leave_types lt
            ON lt.leave_id = eld.leave_type
            Inner Join employee emp
            on emp.PK = eld.emp_id
            Inner JOIN dept_category dc
            ON emp.Emp_Dept_Category = dc.PK
            where eld.leave_current_status_id = :leave_current_status_id";

    $binds = array(
        ":leave_current_status_id"   =>  $leaveCurrentStatus
    );

    $statementEntryCount = $connPDO->prepare($sql);

    $statementEntryCount->execute($binds);
    $queryData = $statementEntryCount->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($queryData);
}


function GetLeaveRequestDetailsById($leaveCurrentStatus, $leaveDetailId){

    global $connPDO;

    $sql = "select *, emp.Employee_Name, emp.Designation, emp.Emp_Dept_Category, lt.Leave_Name
            from tbl_emp_leave_details eld
            Inner join tbl_leave_types lt
            ON lt.leave_id = eld.leave_type
            Inner Join employee emp
            on emp.PK = eld.emp_id
            Inner JOIN dept_category dc
            ON emp.Emp_Dept_Category = dc.PK
            where eld.leave_current_status_id = :leave_current_status_id
            And eld.leave_detail_id = :leave_detail_id";

    $binds = array(
        ":leave_current_status_id"   =>  $leaveCurrentStatus,
        ":leave_detail_id"   =>  $leaveDetailId
    );

    $statementEntryCount = $connPDO->prepare($sql);

    $statementEntryCount->execute($binds);
    $queryData = $statementEntryCount->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($queryData);
}
```

As you can see, both are doing the same work with a small difference, which is `leave_detail_id`. How can I convert these two functions into a single parameterized method to handle both queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I assume that `leave_detail_id` contains an auto-increment value, starting at 1, you can do:

```
function queryDatabase($query, $bindings = [])
{
    global $connPDO;
    // prepare statement 
    $statement = $connPDO->prepare($query);
    // execute statement    
    $statement->execute($bindings);
    // return result in associative array
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function getLeaveRequestDetails($leaveCurrentStatus, $leaveDetailId = 0)
{
    // build query
    $query = "SELECT *, 
                     emp.Employee_Name, 
                     emp.Designation, 
                     emp.Emp_Dept_Category, 
                     lt.Leave_Name
              FROM tbl_emp_leave_details eld
              INNER JOIN tbl_leave_types lt ON lt.leave_id = eld.leave_type
              INNER JOIN employee emp ON emp.PK = eld.emp_id
              INNER JOIN dept_category dc ON emp.Emp_Dept_Category = dc.PK
              WHERE eld.leave_current_status_id = :leave_current_status_id";
    // define bindings
    $bindings = [":leave_current_status_id" => $leaveCurrentStatus];
    // should details id be use? 
    if ($leaveDetailId > 0) {
          $query .= " AND eld.leave_detail_id = :leave_detail_id";
          $bindings[":leave_detail_id"] = $leaveDetailId;
    }
    // query database and return result
    return queryDatabase($query, $bindings);
}
```

I used a [default function argument value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) to set `$leaveDetailId` to zero, if it is absent, when the function is called. If it does get a value bigger than zero the condition is added to the query and the value is bound.

I also removed the actual database querying from this function and put it in a separate function. The reason is that this code can probably be used more often in your scripts. Instead of repeating it every time you can now call `queryDatabase()`.

Finally I removed the `echo json_encode();` from the function. The function name starts with "get" and that almost always implies something will be returned. Also, echoing JSON would restrict this function to that task alone. Now you can still use it to echo JSON, but you can also use it to do something else with the result. A call, returning JSON, would look something like this:

```
echo json_encode(getLeaveRequestDetails("fallen",15));
```

As you can see I've now split your code into more parts than you had before. That's not a bad thing. Now each part performs a single function: Querying the database, getting details of a leave, and echoing JSON. This makes your code easier to read.

In summary:

- Do not repeat yourself ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). This was your reason for asking this question.
- functions should be created with reusability in mind, even the specialized ones. That's [the whole reason for their existance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine#Advantages).
- functions should only perform one task ([Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Comment: This is almost exactly an answer I was writing. I would only add a warning about using global. and offer to pass the connection as a parameter.

Comment: Awesome way to short the code, it is helpful in the context of the question. But as @YourCommonSense suggest we cannot use insert with the specific method.

Comment: This is throwing error "$bindings = []"

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? [Ref.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): "As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].". So you could replace it with `$bindings = array()`.

Comment: I'm not a fan of using dynamically-generated SQL like this. Why not `AND (:param IS NULL OR column = :param)`? That way, you pass in null to indicate to ignore that bit of the query, or the actual value to specify it. It's slightly clunkier, but opens more opportunities for optimization, and makes testing easier.

Comment: @NicHartley That's not a bad idea. I only don't understand which "opportunities for optimization" you're talking about? That must be in the PHP code?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No, in the SQL driver and server. The text has to, at some point, get compiled down into a single actual query; most SQL implementations will do some level of caching. If you use two slightly different queries, you're using up twice as much of the cache; if you use just one, you use less, which means you can fit more into the cache. Also, I don't know if PHP supports this, but some languages will let you precompile a SQL statement and then use it across multiple requests, only changing the parameters.

Comment: @NicHartley Ah, I see what you mean; cache optimizations. Yes, PHP does allow the usage of prepared statements, but you will then probably have to remember it between function calls.

Comment: Good to know! I don't really do anything with PHP, so I'm not at all familiar with how its database access works. Also, for clarity, it doesn't need to be `:param IS NOT NULL`; any 'sentinel' value will work. `:param = 0`, for example, in this case.

Comment: @NicHartley it is quite possible with PHP, I've got an example: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where#static

Answer (score 4):

I was about to write an answer almost *literally* the same as written by KIKO Software (even with the same hyperlinks), so I would only elaborate on it (and somewhat make an answer for the generic question from the question title).

Both `queryDatabase()` and `getResult()` functions from the other two answers are too specific. They cut off the PDO's great ability to [return the database result in *dozens* different formats](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes). So instead of returning just a single format, I would make it rather [a generic PDO query function](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper#function) that returns a `PDOStatement` instance, from which the data could be extracted in any format supported by PDO, so it can be used not only with this particular query but with any query you can think of

```
function pdo($pdo, $sql, $args = NULL)
{
    if (!$args)
    {
         return $pdo->query($sql);
    }
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Examples:

```
$count = pdo($pdo, "SELECT count(*) FROM users")->fetchColumn();
$user = pdo($pdo, "SELECT * FROM users")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$deleted = pdo($pdo, "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=?", [$id])->rowCount();
$indexed_by_id = pdo($pdo, "SELECT id, name FROM users")
     ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

and so on. And of course it would work for your function as well:

```
return pdo($query, $bindings)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Another issue is `global`. Using global keyword is considered rather bad practice and could be justified for only most primitive code. but if you want your code solid and maintainable, always pass a database connection as a function parameter into every function that needs a database interaction. It's little verbose, but will pay back in the future.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that `queryDatabase()` is too specific. It makes more sense to do it this way. I'll leave my answer at it is, so not to spoil your addition.

Comment: what "this" represent in the pdo function? and you didn't use $pdo in the function too?

Comment: It was a typo, fixed now

Answer (score 2):

The code below reduces the duplication you have.

The SQL statement is the first thing that is duplicated, with the exception of the `where` clause. this means we can extract the building of the query to a function that accepts the `where` clause and returns our query.

The result parsing is similar, accepting two parameters instead of one. Rather than just copy the code though, we can leave the `echo` and `json_encode` in the outer function. This means we can reuse the `getSelectStatement` and `getResult` functions elsewhere, where we might not need to echo straight away. We can keep your original functions `GetLeaveRequestDetailsAll` and `GetLeaveRequestDetailsById` for the same reason.

Finally, the single parameterized function you wanted, `GetLeaveRequestDetails`. This has a second parameter that defaults to `null` - you don't have to specify it when you call the function. In practice I would use your two original functions as I believe it's clearer what's going on to people reading the top level of your code, but that's up to you.

As an aside, I'd take a look at what fields you actually need returned from your query. Using `*` is discouraged, particularly if you are echoing the result, as any new fields you add in the future will be printed as well. If the fields are secret, you may not want this.

````php
function GetLeaveRequestDetails($leaveCurrentStatus, $leaveDetailId = null) {

    if ($leaveDetailId) {
        $result = GetLeaveRequestDetailsById($leaveCurrentStatus, $leaveDetailId);
    } else {
        $result = GetLeaveRequestDetailsAll($leaveCurrentStatus);
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}

function GetLeaveRequestDetailsAll($leaveCurrentStatus) {

    $sql = getSelectStatement(
        "where eld.leave_current_status_id = :leave_current_status_id"
    );

    $binds = array(
        ":leave_current_status_id"   =>  $leaveCurrentStatus
    );

    return getResult($sql, $binds);
}


function GetLeaveRequestDetailsById($leaveCurrentStatus, $leaveDetailId) {

    $sql = getSelectStatement(
        "where eld.leave_current_status_id = :leave_current_status_id 
         And eld.leave_detail_id = :leave_detail_id"
    );

    $binds = array(
        ":leave_current_status_id"   =>  $leaveCurrentStatus,
        ":leave_detail_id"   =>  $leaveDetailId
    );

    return getResult($sql, $binds);
}

/** 
 * Both functions use the same query with a different WHERE clause, 
 * so extract that to a function
 */
function getSelectStatement($whereStatement) {

    return "select *, emp.Employee_Name, emp.Designation, 
            emp.Emp_Dept_Category, lt.Leave_Name
            from tbl_emp_leave_details eld
            Inner join tbl_leave_types lt
            ON lt.leave_id = eld.leave_type
            Inner Join employee emp
            on emp.PK = eld.emp_id
            Inner JOIN dept_category dc
            ON emp.Emp_Dept_Category = dc.PK" . $whereStatement
}

/**
 * Both functions parse the query result in the same way, so extract that to a function
 */
function getResult($sql, $binds) {

    global $connPDO;

    $statementEntryCount = $connPDO->prepare($sql);
    $statementEntryCount->execute($binds);
    $queryData = $statementEntryCount->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $queryData;
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks buddy it is helpful but some of the other answer are much smarter

Comment: Please always endorse the consistent usage of ALL CAPS sql keywords for readability.

Comment: I am also not convinced that it is advisable to declare a function merely to prepend a string to another string.  Perhaps less overhead would be to declare the front end of the query string as a globally available constant.